# std::cout not working inside a for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, cout

I'm new to C++, and right now I'm learning from the book called *Accelerated C++*. I finished the third chapter (vectors), and I came to this exercise:

"Write a program to count how many times each distinct word appears in its input."

After some thinking, I started working on it. I wanted to test the program, but std::cout wasn't working. I put `cout << "test";` on a few places in my code to see where's the problem, and the conclusion is that it doesn't work inside the first for-loop. Don't recommend me to use maps to solve the problem, because I'm working on vectors. The variables aren't in English, so I'll translate some for you to know what's going on:

recenica - the sentence; rijec - a word; vel_vektora - size of the vector; duz_recenice - length of the sentence; br_ponavljanja - number of times a word appears in the sentence;

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;      using std::vector;
using std::cin;         using std::cout;
using std::endl;



int main()
{
    string rijec;
    vector<string> recenica;

    while (cin >> rijec) recenica.push_back(rijec);
    cout << endl;

    typedef vector<string>::size_type vel_vektora;
    vel_vektora duz_recenice = recenica.size();
    cout << "test0, ";

    for (int i = 0; i < duz_recenice - 1; ++i)            
    {   
        cout << "test, !";
        int br_ponavljanja = 1;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < duz_recenice; ++j)
        {
                cout << "test2, ";
                if (recenica[i] == recenica[j])
                {
                                cout << "test3, ";
                                ++br_ponavljanja;
                                recenica.erase(recenica.begin() + j);
                }     
                cout << "test4, ";
        }        
        cout << recenica[i] << ": " << br_ponavljanja << endl;        
    }
    cout << "test5, ";                
    getchar();
    return 0;        
}
```

What's the problem with the `std::cout`?

Comment: I suggest you run your app in the debugger, step by step and watch the values of the variables to figure out what the problem is. if you have only one word in the vector, than the outer for loop will not execute

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: @Marius: +1 Thinking about the corner cases is always a good debugging hint.

Comment: @ybungalobill It's not giving me any output.

Comment: FWIW, having variable names in English is a good thing, even if you're not a native English guy (like myself). It helps everyone, and all the APIs/libs you call are in English anyway... (or do you alias std::vector to pl_std::vectory? ;-P)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem in the question, is there a _solved_ button here?

Answer (score 7):

Add `<< flush` to flush your output buffer (each place).

Or use `<< endl`, which both adds newline and flushes.

There are problems with the code, especially for empty input, but that's what  you're out to learn about, so I'll leave you to it! :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the language eludes me in terms of variable names, but this "Works for Me™".

Here is my output (First 3 lines input:)

```
ytreyert
tyryteter
gdhdfgdf
^Z

test0, test, !test2, test4, test2, test4, ytreyert: 1
test, !test2, test4, tyryteter: 1
test5,
```

You should definitely try flushing the cout buffers after printing (as per Alf's answer).

I notice that `gdhdfgdf` is not counted, this is because of this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < duz_recenice - 1; ++i)
```

If you only give 1 input word, this loop will not run, as you do `duz_recenice = recenica.size();` before looping.

Changing this line to

```
for (int i = 0; i < duz_recenice; ++i)
```

solves this problem.

Comment: It works for me too now for some reason, and I did the flushing. What do you want to say with this about the loop? I must determine the number of words, and the for-loop line you wrote is just below it.

Comment: The outer loop in your code iterates over size-1 entries, so it misses out the last word in the vector. Notice my output shows counts for the first two words, but not the last one.

Comment: Oh, I see your point, but I still can't make this program count my words properly. For example, for sentence "i like bread bread likes me",  at the end it counts "me" twice, once giving me number 2, and the second time giving me number 1. That was supposed to be solved by the recenica.erase line.