# cout not working in c++ after taking line input (getline)

Tags: c++, string, cout

I am in midway of implementing fairplay algorithm, but I noticed that `cout` statements are not working

Below is my code. Note that all required header files are included and there are no compilation errors (by far my knowledge). The program runs without errors and I get terminated command (again, with no errors).

But there is no output at the same time. Even the `cout` test 2 is not reflected in output.

NOTE: I get output if I use endl at the end of each cout statement, but thats inconvenient here as I want to print the matrix. Besides there must be a easy way rather than writing enld every time

```
int main()
{

    int i,j,k,x,y,z;
    bool status[24]={false};
    char map[5][5]={0};
    string key;
    cout<<"Enter the key"<<endl;

    cout<<"Test 1";
    getline(cin,key);
    cout<<"Test 2";
    x=key.length();

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        key[i]=toupper(key[i]);

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        y=key[i]-65;
        if(status[y]==0)
            status[y]=1;
    }

    cout<<"Adding the main key string";

    i=j=k=z=0;
    while(k<x)
    {
        if(j==5)
        {
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
        map[i][j++]=key[k++];
    }
    cout<<"Adding the remaining alphabets";
    while(k++<25)
    {
        if(j==5)
                {
                    i++;
                    j=0;
                }
        while(status[z++]==false)
            map[i][j++]=z+64;
    }

    cout<<"Output matrix";
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            cout<<map[i][j];
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please list your include files also in question

Comment: I said there are no errors, all the header files are included

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for guidance, im just a novice, but wouldn't the world be a better place if the "good" people had been a little less arrogant and showed a helping nature to their inferiors.
Rather that being bully/bossy I would be pleased if you could answer to my problem.
"In vain have you acquired knowledge if you have not imparted it to others."

Comment: Looks like you just need to use `cout.flush();` after your outputting lines to see the values appearing immediately after writing them. `cout` uses buffered output with most implementations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank You very much. I apologise if I offended you, its just that I was a bit upset on my question being downvoted. You see its very difficult for a new members like us to increase our  reputation, if people kept on downvoting our questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ BTW wasn't my question worth ??

Comment: @SagarPatel _"BTW wasn't my question worth ??"_ Well, you should have at least put in some efforts to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), instead of providing just a plain code dump. The 1st of the downvotes were probably about that yelling text. That's not well appreciated here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::cout not working inside a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451198/stdcout-not-working-inside-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cout.flush()` (or `std::endl` which implicitly flushes) after each `cout` statement.

`cout` uses buffered output,
using `cout.flush()` will clear the buffer and force the contents being written out.

Thanks  πάντα ῥεῖ for guidance

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
fflush(stdin);
```

after `cout<<"Test 1";` if not working try after `getline(cin,key);`

```
cout<<"Test 1";
getline(cin,key);
cout<<"Test 2";
```

Comment: thanks bro, but I already tried that before and it doesn't work for me

Comment: fflush does not always work. See alternative solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382962/wait-for-press-enter-in-c-inside-a-while-loop/28393414#28393414

Comment: _@Azad_ _`fflush(stdin);`_ You probably meant `cout.flush()`. It's not a good idea to mix c-style IO with c++ IO, and it's not guaranteed to work with all implementations of the language. Also input buffering has nothing to do with the behavior described in the OP.