# cout not working in the case of an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"123";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this small program which would print "123" and then go in an infinite loop. But it does not print anything on the screen. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Maybe it didn't flush it, try `std::cout<<"123"<<std::endl;`

Comment: `cout << "123";` does not necesarrily print anything on the screen, as Melkon pointed out, the stream has to be flushed before anything is printed

Comment: -5? Unduly harsh? Is it really obvious that `<<` is buffering? Then there is the UB sting. This question ain't so bad. OP even got the `main` prototype correct.

Comment: Maybe because it isn't an MCVE. With beginner question, one never knows if code doesn't print because, for example, it didn't even compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::cout not working inside a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451198/stdcout-not-working-inside-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be two reasons.

Firstly, the output is most probably buffered. That is, the text sent to `cout` is not printed immediately, but kept in a buffer and printed only on flushing the buffer (which happens by `cout.flush()` or by printing `endl`).

Secondly, I suppose that an empty infinite loop [is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x). That is, a program with an infinite loop can in fact do absolutely anything; in particular, an optimizer is allowed to optimize anything out of the program.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I do not believe that an infinite loop is UB

Comment: It is (plus one), but with a few provisos.

Comment: @tobi303, added a reference

Comment: It depends on what the infinite loop does. I assume you meant to say "empty infinite loops".

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the process CPU burn (due to the tight loop) has blocked the streaming to the console.

Technically though the behaviour of your program is undefined as, essentially, the loop does not have any input /output or side effects.

A compiler is permitted to optimise out your function body, which would also yield no output.