# Why doesn't std::this_thread::sleep_for() work in MacOS terminal?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11

### Explanation

Take for example this basic code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout << "loop";
    }
}
```

When I run this in XCode, it works exactly as expected. Every second it prints out, "loop". However, when I run this in my terminal, nothing happens. The code seems to be "running" but nothing gets printed to screen.

### Question:

Why does `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` work in the XCode terminal but not the standard MacOS terminal?

Comment: Because the "terminal" buffers your `stdout` whereas it gets flushed immediately by Xcode. Either flush stdout yourself or add `std::endl` at the end which does it implicitly

Comment: @JustSid: Answers in the answers section please.

Comment: @Bathsheba I was writing a fully fleshed out answer after posting the comment. I have incorporated parts of it into the community wiki answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout not working in the case of an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652591/cout-not-working-in-the-case-of-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::this_thread::sleep_for()` works just fine in the Terminal as well, the problem is that `stdout` is buffered on the terminal. `stdout` can either be explicitly flushed or it can be flushed implictly either if it the buffer gets too full or when encountering something like a new line character.

Either flush stdout yourself or add `std::endl` at the end which does it implicitly.

You could also use `std::cerr << "loop";` as the error stream is often unbuffered (although the C++ standard does not insist on that).